# The app is damaged and can’t be opened. Delete the app and download it again from the App Store

Tags: macos, cocoa, app-store, mac-app-store

I have the app for the Mac App Store and I faced with the following problem. Version 1.1 is already in the Mac App Store.

If I change a version of the app to 1.2 and try to run it with a test account I receive the message:

```
The app is damaged and can’t be opened. Delete the app and download it again from the App Store.
```

The Console shows entry:

```
Exited with code: 173
```

I return previous version number 1.1 back, the app starts. I tried to send the app to my colleague. It runs normally. I tried to remove all same binaries from my hard drive. It doesn't help.
I had the same problem before and I even submitted the app in that state to the App Store. It was successfully approved. Now I can run 1.1 with a test account, but I can't run 1.2.

How to solve this issue with App Store?

Comment: If you are an end user seeing [this error on downloaded apps](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/215332/), you might need to `kill -KILL storeaccountd` to refresh invalid or expired receipts. In the case here, it's more about comparing version numbers and caching as described by Craig Hockemberry - http://furbo.org/2013/10/21/mac-app-store-receipts-and-mavericks/

Comment: I have given the answer of above question please visit this link [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26434518/xcode-is-damaged-and-can-t-be-opened-you-should-move-it-to-the-trash/42072155#42072155)

Answer (score 1):

a return code of `173` means the store receipt validation fails.

since you only bought 1.1 from the store, the receipt is for 1.1 and not 1.2.

SO if you change the app's plist to 1.2 the validation fails... receipt 1.1 vs. app 1.2

Comment: this is expected, document behavior

Comment: I didn't buy 1.1 from App Store, even with a redeem code. It's my app, I just compiled it in the Xcode and run with test user from iTunes Connect account. How to update or remove existing receipt?

Comment: "I have the app for the Mac App Store and I faced with the following problem. Version 1.1 is already in the Mac App Store." close enough

Comment: in your app there is a _MASReceipt/receipt file in the app

Comment: but the checking code is from you. so look at YOUR validation code

Comment: if just remove the receipt, it will still fail :D

Answer (score 0):

Try this (it worked for me) :

Open terminal, and type :

```
cd /Applications

sudo chown root Clear.app

sudo chmod 777 Clear.app
```

then open Clear app.

Answer (score -2):

If you trust the people from whom you are downloading things you can bypass the warning by adjusting your ‘Preferences > Security & Privacy’ to

Allow applications downloaded from: Anywhere