# “Xcode” is damaged and can’t be opened. You should move it to the Trash

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode6, osx-yosemite

Installed `XCode 6` on `Mavericks`. It din't run. Updated OS to `Yosemite 10.10` : Now Xcode.app (installed through *.dmg) launch fails with error message `“Xcode” is damaged and can’t be opened. You should move it to the Trash.` Updated to `XCode 6.0.1` through App Store. Still no luck. Same error message. Anyone with a fix?

[image]

Comment: On the newest Sierra update Apple removed the "Anywhere" option from settings, easy fix [right here](https://youtu.be/52gnXsFc3yc)

Comment: @DavidN does that really fix the damaged error? I tried the fix and still doesn't work.

Answer (score 27):

I experienced this error with any new added application under (all) macOS Sierra builds.

The only [solution](https://github.com/docker/kitematic/issues/1637#issuecomment-210924052) that worked for me was to execute :

```
xattr -rc /Applications/<faulty application>.app
```

You can also use the following command to "repair" all applications :

```
xattr -rc /Applications/*.app
```

Answer (score 9):

Some times in below options

- Open System Preferences
- Click on "Security & Privacy"

[image]

Allow apps downloaded from contains only 2 options "Anywhere" is missing for that open your terminal and add below line

```
sudo spctl --master-disable
```

enter your system password. Now you quit **System Preferences** and reopen it **System Preferences/Security & Privacy/General** now "Anywhere" option will be there. Hurrah You have done it.

[image: Problem solved] hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an older question, but if you're like me and absolutely want to install Xcode from a DMG and not from the App Store, there is a way, inspired by [this post](http://conjugateprior.org/2013/08/damaged-and-cant-be-opened/) from Will Lowe that talks about installing an un-signed application.

1. Install the DMG as usual (Double-click, Drag-n-drop)
2. Open System Preferences
3. Click on "Security & Privacy"
4. Adjust the "Allow applications downloaded from:" setting to "Anywhere"
5. Open Xcode
6. Be patient while it verifies and opens

You only need to do this the first time you open Xcode, so you can change your Security settings back to their original value after Xcode has fully launched.

Comment: Yay Apple... No clue why everyone is so hyped up about it. For me it's just one painful stupidity after another. Thanks for solving this one for me...

Answer (score 2):

If you trust the people from whom you are downloading things you can bypass the warning by adjusting your ‘Preferences > Security & Privacy’ to

Allow applications downloaded from: Anywhere

Answer (score 1):

I have just experienced this with Xcode 6.1.1 on Yosemite, except it only happened when I build and run in the simulator - on app launch Xcode would crash and a panel would declare "Xcode is damaged. Delete it and download again from the App Store".

I did all of the following to solve it:

- Delete derived project data and full clean
- Delete app from simulator and quit simulator
- Reboot

Anyway just in case this helps a new visitor to this question :)

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution helpful and follow these steps:

1. run this command into terminal `sudo spctl --master-disable` it may ask your user password.
2. go to *System Preferences* -> *security and privacy* -> *general tab* -> check *Anywhere* option on bottom.

Hope it helps someone.